# Scope Error In Python (Tkinter): "name 'Sample_Name' is not defined", even though it is declared as global

Tags: python, tkinter, scope, toplevel

I am trying to create a **Python GUI** using **Tkinter**. I first create a window displaying options to the user, as buttons. When a button is clicked, I call a function to create a a new window with `Toplevel()` function. In the new window, I have *a button* and *a label*. By clicking the *button* I want the text of the *label* to be changed. However, I get an error about the scope of the *label*. Here is an example of the code's concept:

```
import tkinter as tk

# function called by popWin()
def func():
    global win_lbl    # declaring label as global so that I can edit its text
    win_lbl['text'] = 'new text'    # Here, I get scope error (name 'win_lbl' is not defined)

def popWin():
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    win_btn = tk.Button(window, command = func)       # A button
    win_lbl = tk.Label(window, text = 'initial text') # A label whose name I want to change with func()
    win_btn.grid()
    win_lbl.grid()
    window.mainloop()

# Main Code
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
btn = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Option 1', command = popWin)   # calls popWin, which creates a new window with Toplevel()
btn.grid()
frame.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Full Error text:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Me\Desktop\proj\Menu.py", line 15, in func
    win_lbl['text'] = 'new text'
NameError: name 'win_lbl' is not defined
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to say `global win_lbl` in `popWin()` and not the `func()`

Comment: The variable is 'globalized' in func() yet not initialized. Initialization of the variable in popWin() is unrelated to func(). Move global declaration to popWin() or outside the functions.

Comment: @MaxM _"Outside the functions"_ ?

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Defining a global means you have to define the variable on global scope, i.e. outside of any function. The `global` keyword means that you're telling Python to use the globally defined variable with that name. So, to fix your issue, you have to either put the definition of `win_lbl` at the top of your code outside of any function, pass it to `func` as an argument, or store your functions and everything global in a class and reference that class variable instead.

Comment: I had tried to declare win_lbl as global before the functions' definition, but it did not work. However, after your answer, I tried declaring global on popWin() and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @tsamourid you can't declare a global outside of a function via `global whatever`, you just would do something like `whatever = some_value`. The way to declare a new variable in Python is to assign something to it. Using `global whatever` just means you want to access something that's already been declared, that's all `global` does.